# Parsing IF and IF-ELSE statement in rply

Tags: python, parsing

i want to make one language in Python to train me. But, in conditions, i have an error on parsing. I use RPLY to do this.

I made this grammar :

```py
    @self.pg.production('if_statement : IF expression OPEN_CRO NEWLINE statementlist NEWLINE CLOSE_CRO')
        def ifexp(p):
            return If(p[1], p[4])

        @self.pg.production('if_statement : IF expression NEWLINE OPEN_CRO NEWLINE statementlist NEWLINE CLOSE_CRO')
        def ifexp2(p):
            return If(p[1], p[5])

        @self.pg.production('else_statement : ELSE OPEN_CRO NEWLINE statementlist NEWLINE CLOSE_CRO')
        def elseexp(p):
            return Else(p[3])

        @self.pg.production('else_statement : ELSE NEWLINE OPEN_CRO NEWLINE statementlist NEWLINE CLOSE_CRO')
        def elseexp3(p):
            return Else(p[4])

        @self.pg.production('ifelse_statement : if_statement else_statement')
        def ifelse(p):
            return IfElse(p[0], p[1])

        @self.pg.production('ifelse_statement : if_statement NEWLINE else_statement')
        def ifelse2(p):
            return IfElse(p[0], p[2])
```

But if i make this code :

```
a = enter("Votre age : ")
a = int(a)
if a >= 18
{
    show("Vous etes majeur")
}

show(a)
```

I have an error on the last 'show'.

PS : If i erase the rules about ifelse_statement, it's work (but i can't have if-else condition.)

Thank you (If you want another code, ask it)